# Free up phone storage Android 5.1 Moto G

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G (1st generation) running Android 5.1. Recently, when I put my apps on update the phone refused saying that it had 'insufficient storage'. The [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) app shows that there 9980MB of system data. What exactly is it? How do I free that memory?

[image]

Here is a screenshot of other memory usage:

[image]

Here is the output of `df` on my android device:

[image]

Comment: Your storage card is irrelevant here (see our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for details). What *is* relevant is shown by `df`: `/data` with ~13G capacity is down to ~10% free storage, which triggers the "insufficient storage" error. The tag-wiki also shows what you can do.